# Can't unload packages in R (tidyverse and others)

Tags: r, package, tidyverse

Am relatively new to R and have been working fine with it until yesterday when it won't unload some of my installed packages (tidyverse, ggthemes). I have tried uninstalling the packages and reinstalling them, uninstalling R but nothing seems to work. The packages appear to have downloaded fine, but just won't unpack. The code I am getting is `Error: package or namespace load failed for 'tidyverse' in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as, logical (now), …): ICU init failed: U_FILE_ACCESS_ERROR.ICU init failed: U_FILE_ACCESS_ERROR`.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit late, but you have to restart R studio right after installing the package. If it still doesn't work, you can try checking the R version and update R then load the library again.